# An opinion about circle

Tags: circles, polygons

I'm a student with little knowledge, but I have an opinion about circles which I'd be happy to discuss here. I believe that a circle is a polygon with an enormous number of sides (which I consider as a straight line) and my proof of that is a circle as a 2D shape is a repeat of 1D shapes which are straight lines, like any 2D shape. Also I believe that there is no perfect circle; there are regular polygons considered as circles. And my proof is in our real life if we took any circle and magnified it we'll find straight lines, or if we looked at a circular motion using a femtosecond camera for example, we'll find motions in straight lines.
I've tried to calculate the value of pi by considering the circle as a regular polygon and, I've got the same value of rounded pi on my calculator.
Can any one prove I am wrong or right or discuss me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I should just point out that a circle is kind of like a polygon with an infinite number of sides. However, your proof is unclear. There are indeed "perfect" circles, especially in the abstract. I'm not really sure what you mean by calculating pi by considering the circle as a regular polygon, either.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [Archimedes' Calculation](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2012-02) of the area of a circle, which indeed approximates the circle by regular polygons.  But, in the end, approximations, however enlightening and useful, are just approximations.

Comment: As soon as term "perfect circle" comes up, you should _completely forget about physical reality_.

Comment: Many math objects are "idealization" out of the real world. I provide a question for you: If you are given a figure and told that the figure is a square with side length $3$cm, what is its area? To answer this question, don't even try to measure each side length by a ruler at hand and report that the figure is not a square... :) I call such an act "being scientific"; it is not about math, not at all.

Comment: Try reading G. H. Hardy's "A Mathematician's Apology", which might be helpful given your situation.

Comment: There are many other books that you can find fruitful ; among others : "One Hundred Problems in Elementary Mathematics" by Hugo Steinhaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a perfect circle can exist in real life has no bearing on the mathematics. A circle in mathematics is an abstract concept, not something related to the real/physical world.

You're right that you can approximate the value of $\pi$ by considering regular polygons. In fact, this is what Archimedes did a long time ago. But no matter how many sides you use, it's never going to be a perfect circle. And you need an increasingly large amount of sides of the polygon, as you increase the desired precision of the approximation.

However, you could probably view the circle as the limit of regular $n$-gons ( this limit is not a polygon itself, though).